# Is there any way (not patching gnome-terminal) for an interactive shell to know the terminal window?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I can accept an extra application to communicate between the WM/terminal and the shell.

I do not need to identify the terminal/console type, but the window ID, so I could do some action on the window. The PS way does not simply work with gnome-terminal. The shell is a subprocess of terminal service, not the window itself.

OS: Artful.

Comment: I'm probably missing what you're after, but `echo \`ps | tail -n 1 | awk {'print $2'}\`` does what I understand your subject is asking...

Comment: @guiverc the `echo` and backticks are superfluous in that pipeline, and I would prefer the `tty` coreutil for that. But I agree that we may be missing exactly what OP is asking. What does to "know the terminal window" mean?

Comment: As it happens I recently wrote an answer about that…

Comment: @guiverc Also as PIDs wrap around as they reach their maximum value, there's absolutely no guarantee that the last printed line would be any relevant.